# MySQL check id whether is in another table

Tags: sql, mysql

How to check whether the id from one table is in another table in the same database. If it is then the row should not be returned.

table1:
id int(11) unsigned primary key,
data varchar(25) default ''

table2:
id int(11) unsigned primary key,
tableone_id int(11) unsigned,
another_data varchar(11) default''

the query checks whether id from table one is in table two table (the fields compared are 
table1.id and table2.tableone_id
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.id = table2.tableone_id
WHERE table2.tableone_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the most efficient, but:

`SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.tableone_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table1)`